# Is the norm of a non-negative vector always smaller than the norm of the sum of two non-negative vectors?

Tags: normed-spaces

I am not a mathematician, so this question may be trivial, but I do not know whether it is correct or not. So any help is appreciated

Let $u$ and $v$ be two non-negative vectors, i.e., all elements in both vectors are non-negative.
Intuitively, I would say that the following inequality holds:$$\|u\| \leq \|u+v\|,$$
i.e., the norm over $u$ is smaller then the norm over the sum of $u$ and $v$. As the norm basically defines the 'length', the sum of non-negative vectors $u$ and $v$ should give a larger 'length'.

My question is, does this statement hold? And if so, what would be a proof?

**Edit:** I actually ment non-negative vectors instead of positive vectors. Thanks Rob Arthan for pointing this out.

Comment: Each component of $u+v$ is at least as big as the respective component of $u$, so the squares will be at least as big, so the sum of squares will be at least as big.

Comment: Are you thinking of the usual norm?  That is $||(u_1,\cdots, u_n)||=\sqrt {u_1^2+\cdots +u_n^2}$?

Comment: Intuitively, this can be seen as "obvious" if one considers positive as "motion away" from the origin (increases distance from). The addition of two positive vectors means the object moves away from the origin in two steps.

Comment: JairTaylor and lulu thanks for the answers, indeed I see that it is quite trivial for the euclidean norm or any l-norm (I think). Does this already cover all possible norm cases?

Comment: @DavidPeterson: the general notion of norm, does not follow your intution (see the examples in the answers below): under some norms, a sideways step can bring you nearer to your goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let me assume you are working with the usual Euclidean norm on the real $n$-dimensional vector space, $\Bbb{R}^n$. sLet $u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ and $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ where the $u_i$ and $v_i$ are positive real numbers. Then for each $i$, $u_i < u_i+v_i$, so
$$
\|u\| = \sqrt{u_1^2 + \ldots u_n^2} < \sqrt{(u_1+v_1)^2 + \ldots (u_n+v_n)^2} = \|u + v\|
$$
If you want the analogous result with "non-negative" in place of "positive", just replace each $<$ above by $\le$.

You can ignore the rest of this answer if you are not interested in more general [norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

In general, a norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is completely determined by its unit disc, $D$, which can be an arbitrary convex body that is symmetric about the origin, i.e., $D = -D$. In $\Bbb{R}^2$ you can define a norm whose unit disc is the parallelogram with vertices at $(-1, 0)$, $(1, 1)$, $(1, 0)$ and $(-1, -1$). Under this norm $\|(0, 1/2)\| = 1 > \|(3/4, 3/4)\| = 3/4$.

Comment: I indeed see that this works for the Euclidean norm, would you happen to know if this generalises for all norms?

Comment: @RobArthan I guess you mean $\Vert u+v\Vert$ instead of $\Vert v\Vert$  :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: thanks for pointing out the error. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not the case for all norms.  Consider the norm on $\mathbb R^2$ corresponding to the inner product

$\langle [x_1, x_2], [y_1, y_2] \rangle = x_1 y_1 -  (x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1) + 2 x_2 y_2$

This is a norm because the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 2\cr}$ is 
positive definite.

We have $$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \| [x,y] \|^2 = 
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} (x^2 - 2  x y + 2 y^2) = 
-2 x + 4 y$$
so e.g. taking $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, $\|[1,0] + [0,\epsilon]\| < \|[1,0]\|$ for small enough $\epsilon > 0$ (in fact for $0 < \epsilon < 1$).

EDIT: Ok, $[1,0]$ and $[0,\epsilon]$ don't have **strictly** positive entries, but by continuity the inequality will work for 
$[1,\delta]$ and $[\delta, \epsilon]$ if $\delta > 0$ is small.

Comment: Mea culpa: you are right that this property of the Euclidean norm does not hold for all norms . I've added an example to my answer that uses a norm with a polygonal unit disc to achieve a similar effect to the ellipse that is the unit disc in your example.

Comment: @RobArthan at least it is true for all $p$-norms.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Consider the norm $$\|(x,y)\| = |x| + |x-y|$$
on $\Bbb{R}^2$. Then
$$\|(1,1)\| = 1 < 2 = \|(1,0)\|.$$